# Como saber se o último caractere de uma string termina com a letra "a" ou "o"?

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de fazer um código que veja se o ultimo caractere de uma string termina com a letra "a" ou "o" para identificar se a palavra é masculina ou feminina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar a última letra de uma palavra use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php):

```
substr("testers", -1); // retorna "s"
```

> Se o 2º parâmetro (conhecido como **start**) for negativo, a string retornada irá começar no caractere start **a partir do fim da string**.

Então para verificar a condição atribua a uma variável e verifique se o valor é "a" ou "o":

```
$ultima = substr("testers", -1);
if ($ultima == "a") {
    echo "Feminina";
}
elseif($ultima == "o") {
    echo "Masculina";
}else{
    echo "A palavra não termina com 'a' ou 'o'";
}
```